# Apache Tomcat Singleton replication with Autoload

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, singleton, classloader

I'm developing a framework used by web-applications based on tomcat.

I'm forced to use sometimes the Singleton Pattern for several reason.

When I perform a deploy with autoload (moving the war file in the webapps folder) I notice that the previous singleton instance is never deallocated.
Each time i perform a deploy in this way a new instance of the singleton class will be placed in the heap (just the correct one is used by the web application). I'm feared that this will produce memory leaks. 
I've an heap dump that confirm this.

I'm aware that using autoload feature in a production environment is not a good practise but I'm working on a framework that would be likely to be used by many people. 
This way I can't guess their deploy-strategy.

Comment: I guess your case could be similar to the one in which you may have multiple class loaders? See e.g. [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html?page=2). Hope it helps.

Comment: it's not this case. I'm sure that the Singleton Pattern is implemented in a right way (I've used the ENUM implementation). The servlet container uses the specific web application ClassLoader. The problem is that the Garbage Collector can't perform his action on this objects because they have a reference to themself... I don't know how to avoid this effect after an hot deploy